# Entity Framework with B2C Auth redirects to empty page, when called with postman "url-missmatch"

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When I try to make the following API call:

`https://skillbasedmiddleware.azurewebsites.net/tables/useritem?$filter=(email eq '55@55.de')`

I'm redirected to a "logging on" window, but then stays empty.

When I try to make a request to the URL via postman (without any auth token) I am getting:

```html
<input type='hidden' name='error' id='error' value='redirect_uri_mismatch'/>
<input type='hidden' name='error_description' id='error_description' value='AADB2C90006: The redirect URI&#39;https://skillbasedmiddleware.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc&#39; provided in the request is not registered for the client id &#39;XXX;. Correlation ID: 586439a6-0be6-45f1-aab2-b382dcb8f935' />
```

My first question: Is it right that I am redirected and that the window stays blank?
My second question: Why is there a "URI MISSMATCH"?

Here is my API configuration:

```json
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://xxx.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "yyyy",
    "Domain": "ccc.onmicrosoft.co",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-oidc",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_Client"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Here is my API startup code:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection1");
    
if (connectionString == null)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("DefaultConnection is not set");
}

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureADB2C"));
    
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to 
    // the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
    
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MigrationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatasyncControllers();
    
var app = builder.Build();
    
// Initialize the database
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MigrationDbContext>();
    //await context.InitializeDatabaseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
    
// Configure and run the web service.
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Where could the issue be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make an API then no, it's not right that you're being redirected to B2C, you should be receiving a 401 Unauthorized response instead.

It looks like this is happening because you've configured your API to authenticate as [a web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-overview?tabs=aspnetcore) (`AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp`), rather than [a web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview) (`AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi`).

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-api?tabs=csharpclient) should provide an example of setting that up using B2C but you'll need to:

1. Create an app registration in B2C representing your MAUI app (I think you've already done this)
2. Create an app registration in B2C representing your API
3. Expose permissions from your API app registration that you can use to restrict access in your API code
4. Grant those permissions to your MAUI app registration
5. Configure your API app to authenticate API calls.
6. When the MAUI app requests tokens for your user include your API app registration as an additional scope (you should be told what value to use when exposing permissions in step 3)
7. Pass the access_token you receive for your API with all of your API requests

Comment: Thank you for your input. Well, I am trying to connect from my MAUI app, so it IS a mobile app. That may be the issue with postman; that its comming from web? Because then no change is required and the behavoir is to be expected, right?

Comment: Hmm, something doesn't sound right about your setup. If you go to the link in your original post then it redirects to B2C, so it's that web app that's the relying party and that web app that B2C will redirect back to, so the app registration needs to be for a web app. I'm not familiar with the setup of MAUI apps, but it's only if that app itself is acquiring tokens would the app registration should be a mobile/native app.

Comment: the app itself is acquiering tokens (or at least thats what im trying) to access my middleware. I got to the point where the azure ad b2c log on screen opensin my app, i can sign in and once I check out the token I unfortunately see, that "accessToken" is null. (token Id however is being returned.) 
but for setup this should be about right, or not? This is a bit overwheling for me...

Comment: Ahh, okay, that makes a bit more sense. So is https://skillbasedmiddleware.azurewebsites.net/tables/useritem?$filter=(email eq '55@55.de') an API that you're trying to call from your MAUI app that would return JSON or XML?

Comment: yes, that is the case. This did work before I added auth to it. (When the API was just online for everyone). But now I want to access it with my token...

Comment: Okay, cool. Let me make a few edits to the question & my answer, hopefully that should help you out.

Comment: HOLY SMOKES; YOU SOLVED IT!" IT WAS LITERALLY 2 LETTRS: It was that: AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi thank you so much!